# Access $scope.property inside ng-repeat loop

Tags: angularjs

How do I access a property on the `$scope` from within the `ng-repeat` loop? In the code below, the thumbnail index is set on the controller. The view need to use this property from inside `ng-repeat`.

```
//Controller
    $scope.thumbnailIndex = 4;

//View
        <div id="album">
            <ul id="photosList">
                <li ng-repeat="photo in photos">
                    <img ng-src="{{photo.thumbnails[??].url}}" ng-click="details(photo.id)"/>
                </li>
            </ul>        
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are trying to do is this:

```
<img ng-src="{{photo.thumbnails[thumbnailIndex].url}}" ng-click="details(photo.id)"/>
```

If your view/include controller is the current scope, then just drop the `$scope.` prefix and you can use the variables wherever you want.

Comment: I swear I tried this before but it didn't work. Now it seems to work. Weird. Thank you very much. The look on the Grumpy cat tells me I should've checked my code before asking.